# QGIS 2.10.1 (64bit) rotation field setting missing

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-2.10

I cannot find the the rotation field setting under the properties-layer settings-advanced (for styles) menu in the new release of QGIS (2.10.1 64bit). The only setting what is available there is the "symbol levels". Any idea where can I find this function?

Comment: Awesome buddy, will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS 2.10.1, the option **Change angle** is availabe for the *Rule-based* style which can be used for rotation. This can be accessed by right-clicking on an item.

Answer (score 1):

It's now set via the data defined button next to the symbols angle property. Just click that button and choose your field you want to bind the rotation to.

Comment: +1, Thanks for answering and clarifying buddy, I do not have QGIS 2.10 to test this with.