# QGIS 2.10 symbol rotation is absent

Tags: qgis-2.10

my layer is point, and the symbol are "ellipse" with categorized renderer.
So I define rotation in data defined properties but the tool «rotate» still inactive (rotation data works in QGIS 2.8).

Where the rotation properties must be defined : in the "MARKER» level or in "SYMBOL" level or the both ?

With the 10 symbols, I must make 10 times the same operations (in marker or in symbol level)?

The rotation is no longer in advanced menu, maybe in the over menu (and I can't see it) ?

Comment: another question has the answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156113/qgis-2-10-1-64bit-rotation-field-setting-missing

Comment: Yes, I see it but it's not the same thing.I define the symbol angle property.